# How to get nested object's attributes from model.toJSON

Tags: backbone.js

I am learning Backbone.js. I have a model call myModel, and here is the console.log result when I call myModel.toJSON():

```
Object {accountId: "523f628e80d52a2805000004", added: "2013-09-26T06:26:12.765Z", updated: "2013-09-26T06:26:12.765Z", _id: "5243d384951b6cef05000004", name: Object}
```

I want to get the attributes in name, when I console.log myModel.toJSON().name, I got this result:

```
Object {first: "myfirst", last: "mylast"}
```

Everything works fine, until I call myModel.toJSON().name.first, I got a console error says

```
Cannot read property 'first' of undefined
```

I thought myModel.toJSON().name is an object, and to get the 'first' attribute from it, I just need to do myModel.toJSON().name.first. Any thought why it doesn't work?

This is the entire model I have:

```
r {cid: "c71", attributes: Object, collection: r, _changing: false, _previousAttributes: Object…}
_changing: false
_events: Object
_pending: false
_previousAttributes: Object
attributes: Object
_id: "5243d384951b6cef05000004"
accountId: "523f628e80d52a2805000004"
added: "2013-09-26T06:26:12.765Z"
name: Object
first: "myfirst"
last: "mylast"
__proto__: Object
updated: "2013-09-26T06:26:12.765Z"
__proto__: Object
changed: Object
cid: "c71"
collection: r
__proto__: s
```

Comment: working fine for me… http://jsfiddle.net/TJZ7Z/1/ are you sure it isn't something else in your model? May be post your entire model? `toJSON()` just returning your `attributes` see this http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-36

Comment: I just post the entire model.

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using `myModel.get(...)`?